# Convert a .csv file into a 2D table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

as the title suggests I'd like to know how to convert a .csv file in Lua into a 2D table.

So, for example, say I have a .csv file that looks like this:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0
0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0
0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0
0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0
0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0
0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

How would I convert it into something like this?

```
local example_table = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0},
{0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0},
{0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0},
{0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0},
{0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0},
{0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace each newline with `"},\n{"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Don't underestimate CSV.

If you need it generic, get a proper CSV parsing library. If you do the parsing yourself, you will miss lots of special cases that *could* happen, so it's only suitable for cases where you know your data and would notice if something went wrong.

## 2. Changing the file

If you want the equivalent **Lua code** as output, assuming you're doing the parsing in Lua, you could do something like this:

```lua
local input = get_input_somehow() -- probably using io.open, etc.

local output =
"local example_table = {\n"
..
input:gmatch("[^\n]*", function(line)
   return "{" .. line .. "};"
end)
..
"\n}"

save_output_somehow(output) -- Probably just write to a new file
```

## 3. Parsing CSV into a table

If you want to read the CSV file directly into a Lua table, you could instead do it like this:

```lua
local input = get_input_somehow() -- probably using io.open, etc.

local output = {}
input:gmatch("[^\n]", function(line)
   local row = {}
   table.insert(output, row)
   line:gmatch("[^,]", function(item)
      table.insert(row, tonumber(item))
   end)
end)

do_something_with(output) -- Whatever you need your data for
```